# How do I make a clickable button redirect only after form has been filled out

Tags: html

I am a beginner in html code and created a clickable button however I am stumped how to make it clickable only after the form has been filled out. basic code I have so far is :

```
<a href="your landing page url">
<img src="your image url" />
</a>
```

what must I add to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: Please include the code for the form, and some code for what you have tried so far.

Comment: There is no form in your code

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply just wanting to use html and vanilla javascript to disable a button form then use the disable property.

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="text" onkeyup="inputFill(this)" />
    <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" disabled />
</body>

<script>
    function inputFill(inputData) {
        var btn = document.getElementById('submitBtn');
        if (inputData.value.length > 0) {
            btn.disabled = false;
        }
        else {
            btn.disabled = true;
        }
    }    
</script>
</html>
```

This should give you a start on what to do